# Linkedin Access-token fails to retrieve public profile but succeeds if delayed by 5 sec or more

Tags: ruby-on-rails, get, request, linkedin-api

when i call the below controller method to fire a GET request

```
def get_user_data
   uri = URI.parse("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json")
   request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
   request["Authorization"] = 'Bearer BLBLBLBLBLLBLBACCESS_TOKEN'

   req_options = {
      use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
   }

   resp = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
      http.request(request)
   end

   (resp.kind_of? Net::HTTPOK) ? resp.body : "Invalid request token."
end
```

I get this response:

```
body: |-
{
    "errorCode": 0,
    "message": "Then token used in this request has been revoked by the user.",
    "requestId": "AM2SJ9JBQG",
    "status": 401,
    "timestamp": 1510052511020
}
```

But when i issue the below "identical" request using curl I get a proper response JSON

```
C:\Windows\system32>curl "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json" -H "Authorization: Bearer BLBLBLBLBLLBLBACCESS_TOKEN"
{
   "firstName": "*****",
   "headline": "********",
   "id": "*********",
   "lastName": "*************",
   "siteStandardProfileRequest": {"url": "*******************"}
 }
```

Any suggestions? I thought the two GET-requests are identical.
Can anyone see the difference or point me to the right direction?

**UPDATE**

If I introduce a delay of minimum 5 seconds (sleep 5) just before issuing the GET-request then it works. Go figure! But this cannot be the way to go. I hope! Any help much appreciated.
NOTE: With sleep 3 it still doesnt work!

**UPDATE No 2**

Since the request has produced a valid access-token which is proven by the fact that if I wait for 5 seconds or more than the GET request (using the received token) goes to Linkedin and is served successfully, I am assuming that the access_token given by linkedin is not directly usable but requires some time to be activated. Therefore, the actual question's title may now be misleading and is therefore changed.

Comment: Do you get the very same error if you comment `request["Authorization"]` row?

Comment: request.add_field 'Authorization', 'huda7da97hre3rhr1yrh0130409u1u'
 try this one

Comment: @Tushar: getting the same error

Comment: @AntonTkachov: In this case I am getting:"message": "Unknown authentication scheme",

Comment: headers = {
    'Authorization'=>'Bearer: foobar',
    'Content-Type' =>'application/json',
    'Accept'=>'application/json'
}

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
response = http.post(uri.path, params.to_json, headers)  try this

Comment: I think, that problem is in token itself, not in the request. I foreseen several cases: 1. Token was outdated/stale during ruby request 2. Linkedin reject second request, because of some security algorythms

Comment: @AntonTkachov: but if i issue the same request with curl (using the same token) multiple times. All of them succeed. And now even via ruby introducing the mentioned delya of 5 seconds or more , it also succeeds

Comment: @TusharPal: Its a GET not a POST request. What is "params" in your suggestion?

Comment: @TusharPal we are seeing the same thing outside of Ruby.  Has anyone reached out to linkedin about this issue?

Comment: I happen to have the same issue as this. I spent few hours looking for any changes or updates to the libraries, and in the end I managed to get the API return a proper response when adding `time.sleep(6)` in my library before calling the `/people/~` endpoint. Using Python but was getting the same `401` message. Any updates regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
res = Net::HTTP.get_response(...
```

or follow from the docs (https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-How+to+use+Net-3A-3AHTTP) how to get the response

```
Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri

  response = http.request request # Net::HTTPResponse object
end
```

Comment: I am getting the same error. Only in case of adding 5 secs delay before the request, the attempt succeeds

Comment: Did you try get_response too?

Comment: How can I use get_response if I need to add parameters to the header too?

Comment: https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-get_response

Comment: How does this help?